# how to write a distance active record

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to PHP codeigniter. I need a big help from you people. This is one of my project matter. The thing is i'm going to access a table in the database in order to calculate the distance. Table name is gps_info. In there, there are two attributes which can be used to calculate the distance. Those are `speed` and `timestamp`. This my active record

```
public function get_distance() {
    $this->db->select('speed','timestamp');
    $this->db->from('gps_info');
    $this->db->orderby('gps_info.id','desc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

This is not correct.. Can you help me please how to write this service correctly :)

Comment: Perhaps you want to get the time interval and multiply by speed? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: $this->db->last_query(); check your query by printing it

Comment: yes LFlare. Both speed and timestamp valuesare come are save inside the db table. from their i have to take those and calculate distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working code for fetching the data what you want:

```
public function get_distance()
{
    $res = $this->db->select('speed, timestamp')
      ->from('gps_info')
      ->orderby('id', 'desc')
      ->get()
      ->result_array();

     return $res;

}
```

Comment: I want to know how i could i get the multiplication of these two attributes. Is it as follows, public function get_distance()
{
    $res = $this->db->select('speed * timestamp')
      ->from('gps_info')
      ->orderby('id', 'desc')
      ->get()
      ->result_array();

     return $res;

}

Comment: I don't understand your second question. You can fetch this from the database (with my code) and you can access it from an array. The function returns to an array, so you can: `foreach ($result as $item) { $multiplied = $item['speed'] * $item['timestamp']; }` and you can do whatever you want with that in this loop.

Comment: Is this part coming uder service or the controller part

Comment: And my next question is the answer coming from this multiplication should be subtracted from 10. How to do that

Comment: This is the controller part, and you can do whatever you want, so you can substract from 10 before or after the multiplication. It's simple php from that point.

Answer (score 0):

Your select portion is wrong, it should be:

```
$this->db->select('speed, timestamp');
```